# Loop for new Google Map Marker for every JSON object in database

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps

I'm working with a friend to create a Google Map marker for every entry in a table - I have a loop but I'm not sure I've got it right. The map works fine, I can add normal markers and can loop through the entries and `append` them to a `div` but when I try to use the marker code in the loop I get the following errors for every entry in the console:

`InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

`InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama`

Does this mean that the database isn't saving the lat/long as a number? Here is a shorter version of the code I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getAllJson.php',
    success: function(jsonData) {
        var obj = (jsonData);
        $.each(obj, function(key,value) {
            //console.log(key, first, value[1], value[2]);
            var user = {
                id: value["id"],
                firstName: value["first_name"],
                lastName: value["last_name"],
                email: value["email"],                 
                lat: value["latitude"],                  
                long: value["longitude"]
            };

            var firstName = user.firstName,
                lastName = user.lastName,
                email = user.email,
                userLat = user.lat,
                userLong = user.long;

            // marker
            var markerLatLng = {lat: userLat, lng: userLong};

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerLatLng,
                map: map
            });


        }); 

    }
});
```

Am I on the right track or is there a better/easier way to loop through all the entries and create a marker based on the lat/long? Thanks!

Comment: Try `var markerLatLng = {lat: parseFloat(userLat), lng: parseFloat(userLong)};`

Comment: show me where you have created your map. Is is it a global instance?

Comment: [this](http://imgur.com/a/bgk2R) is my main.js file - the code above the `mapInit` function is just some jQuery for unrelated bits to the map

Comment: Yeah sorry, I added that screenshot before I saw your comment asking for the code

Comment: next time, don´t post an image of your code, create a fiddle!!!

Comment: My bad, will do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve two problems here.

The first is to parse userLat/ userLong to floats. This can be done as mentioned above in my comment:

```
var markerLatLng = {lat: parseFloat(userLat), lng: parseFloat(userLong)};
```

The other Problem you are facing is, that you map instance isn´t reachable, because you have defined it locally in initMap. To fix this, you simply make

```
var map;

function mapInit(){
  map = new google.maps.Map('');
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Thanks! :-)